# rails slim very simple questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm new to slim and there are little things that I don't understand and I don't find answers in the documentation.

1. linebreak - How can I add this at the end of a line? For example:

   `<%= name %><br/>`

   `<%= address %><br/>`
2. How can I combine pure html and ruby on the same line? For example:

   `<p>New building <% if building.ownver %> for <%= owner %><% end %></p>`

I know, I must have missed something but there is no real tutorial out there.

BTW, There is no emulator to convert erb to slim?

Thanks.

Comment: In erb, I tend to use `<p>New building <%= "for #{owner}" if building.owner %></p>` rather than `<p>New building <% if building.owner %> for <%= owner %><% end %></p>` for these scenarios.

Comment: It's indeed cleaner but less appropriate to illustrate my question! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this converter html to slim here's [a link](http://html2slim.herokuapp.com/)!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation covers this here: https://github.com/slim-template/slim#inline-html--html-style

The example it gives is:

```
<html>
  head
    title Example
  <body>
    - if articles.empty?
    - else
      table
        - articles.each do |a|
          <tr><td>#{a.name}</td><td>#{a.description}</td></tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know if there's an equivalent to the erb `<%= "for #{owner}" if building.ownver %>` in slim, so I would just use the above information for your second question, as well, by changing the code to:

```
- if building.ownver
  <p>New building</p>
- else
  <p>New building for #{owner}</p>
```

Comment: If I understand right, the solution to my first question would be: #{name}<br/> ? Seems to work but strange. What would then be the answer to the second question? Thx!